# OnRestoreInstanceState() not applied on View IDs that have been set programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager, state

I have a ViewGroup that programmatically instantiates and assigns an ID to a ViewPager.  On rotation, the "Up" button and changing the screen orientation will recreate the Views -- but it doesn't remember the last page index of the ViewPager.

I've verified that OnSaveInstanceState() and OnRestoreInstanceState() are both being called, and both of them contain the correct page index information.  But, the ViewPager gets reset to page index to 0 regardless.  I notice that I get I message in the console

`No package identifier when getting name for resource number [id that I programmatically defined]`

As an experiment, I defined the ViewPager (along with the ID) in XML.  It does correctly set the ViewPager to the last page index.

So, what I suspect is that the Android framework can't actually restore the last state correctly because the ID doesn't persist when the ViewGroup then ViewPager gets destroyed.

How can I get this to work?  I'd like to contain all state relating things within this ViewGroup (eg avoid keeping track of the ViewPager position in Fragment).  But, it doesn't seem like I can get this to work unless I can make the ID persist (if that's the root cause).

Comment: Can't you simply use the `ViewGroup`'s onSave/onRestoreInstanceState methods to save that position yourself(I'm assuming that you're using a custom class)?

Comment: @Luksprog yeah, but I'm running into another issue where calling `ViewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)` doesn't actually take effect.  By letting the ViewPager call its own `OnRestoreInstanceState()` will set the page index correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: There was a race condition in my code.  After ensuring that I have a unique ID, it worked perfectly.**

It seemed to me that (for some odd reason), an ID of less than 10 would return incorrect instance data (possibly from another view) to the OnRestoreInstanceState() of the ViewPager.

Really weird since I used `FindViewByID` prior to setting the ID to ensure that the ID was unique.  But, there could be a race condition or something that I'm missing.

Anyways, setting the ID to 10 or greater gave the correct behavior, and the position of the ViewPager persists between orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years from OP's post but I think it worth to mention some possible issues here for people after me.

In OP's original post, the solution to restoring the id you set programmatically is to save the view's id in its parent level. So when restore, the parent will recreates the view and set the restored id back to the new view. This way you can restore all data you have saved in this view before configuration change.

In the OP's own answer, my guess is you are assigning the same id to multiple views. For instance, you have view A and view B, and you accidentally set the same id to both. Later on when you are trying to restore saved state from view A after configuration change, you probably restored B's saved state. Thus you are getting incorrect instance data. Note B could be not a normal view, it could also be menu items or anything the OS considers a view. Your solution for setting id larger than 10 just because your second view(B) has a id less than 10, so you are lucky for this time. Dig through your code and see if you made the same mistake I made.

Comment: This kind of looks like a comment, since it mostly addresses other posts, but I think you could rework it to standalone by addressing a full solution, bottom to top, and explaining why the particular parts are necessary (without explicitly mentioning other answers).

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'd like to add comment if I could, my account is new and I don't have enough reputation to gain the "comment privilege"... I'm just trying to help if others encounter the same problem.